# Assets folder for Windows 8 Phone app

Tags: windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013, assets

I have an app for Android that I'm porting to Windows Phone 8 now.
The assets folder lies apart of code in my folder sturucture. In order to include it into Android build, I use `<linkedResources>`.

Is there anything similar for Windows Phone 8 and MSVC? Having examined examples, I found they all include assets directly into project folder structure in Visual Studio. Can I avoid copying assets into MSVC project folder?

BTW, my MSVC 2013 does not have drop box on `Add` button:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This an old Silverlight trick when there was common `entity` code files which needed to be shared between the app and the service where the library could not be brought in due to the differences in .Net.

The trick is to include as a link into the project. Here is how

1. In the assets folder of the WP8 phone project right click and select `Add` then `Existing Item...` or `shift` `alt` `A`.
2. Browse to the location of the file(s) found in the android project and select the file(s).
3. Once the item(s) have been selected, then on the `Add` button select the drop down arrow.
4. Select `Add as link` to add the image(s) as a link into the folder.
   [image]

That will give access to the file *as if* the file was actually within the project's `Asset` folder, but the file physically resides elsewhere.

Comment: Thank you, but I do not see a drop down arrow on the `Add` button. I am using MSVC 2013.

Comment: @Nick see picture from VS2013.

Comment: Please see screenshot from my VS2013. Something wrong with my MSVC?

Comment: @Nick which version of Visual Studio 2013 are you using?

Comment: @Nick create a brand new folder in your project and try to do an `Add` then `Existing item` to that folder. Does the same happen?

Comment: @Nick In researching this problem others (on different versions) who are not using the `English` version seem to have this problem...I am wondering if it is an actual bug.

Comment: I am using English MSVC-2013 Professional Update 2 and Russian Windows 8.1. Maybe you are right and it's a Microsoft bug. Okay I will try to manually set all that stuff in vcxproj files. Thanks for your effort.