# Keeping source folder structure in windows runtime application assets

Tags: c++, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, windows-8.1

I am trying to create a Windows runtime application (in c++) and I want to store some "external" files in the application's Assets. I figured out there is a 'Content' flag which makes the file included in the package. However, if files are not located in the solution folder, all the files from all subfolders go directly into the Assets folder, which creates a huge mess. I want to keep my source folder structure. This works if the assets are located in the solution folder, but this is inconvenient for me.
On Android, you simply specify any assets folder location, and this folder is packaged as is. Can I do something like this on windows?

This post sort of gives answer to this question: [Assets folder for Windows 8 Phone app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24432598/assets-folder-for-windows-8-phone-app).
However it feels like almost nobody including me have that drop-down option on the Add button (I am using VS2013 Ultimate Update 4).
So is there another solution? Can I for instance edit the visual studio project by hands?

Answer (score 0):

Add as Link is only available for C# and VB Projects.

Comment: That is good to know, thank you. But still, do you know if there is a way to include assets from outside the solution folder?